# matlab, plotting 2 vecctors as a list, how can I give them different line types and colours using this syntax

Tags: matlab, plot

I have checked SO and ML help but cannot see a solution to this.

using this syntax

```
E = 10; % amplitude
sample_1_hz = 1000;
sample_2_hz = 11000;
fs = 10000; % sample rate in Hz
Samples = 100;
time_scale = (0:Samples-1)'/fs;
sig_1 = E*sin(2*pi*time_scale*sample_1_hz);
sig_2 = E*sin(2*pi*time_scale*sample_2_hz);

plot(time_scale,[sig_1 sig_2]);

grid('on');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('1000 Hz', '11000 Hz');
```

how can I alter the lines to have different line styles and colors?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It has plenty of examples that show how to accomplish this. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

Comment: Hi Cris there are a number of examples showing how to change the colour of a single line but I cannot see how to change the colour or each line when multiple are passed as a vector.. maybe I am missing it?

Comment: You're not passing a vector, `[sig_1 sig_2]` is a 2D array. `plot` returns an array of handles, one for each line plotted. Using the handles you can change all of the line's properties.

Comment: I did try the following [sig_1 'r' sig_2 'b'] but to no avail. You are saying that plot returns an array of handles, so I can modify the handles after calling the function.? How does it look?

Comment: See this example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#bt246ud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the two lines coincide in every point in `time_scale` in the example code you posted (plot their difference  `sig_1-sig_2` and see the values in the 1e-13), so the only way to see both of them is to make one "dashed" and the other "solid" so you can see one on top of the other , or add a marker to one of them. for example,

```
plot(time_scale, sig_1 ,'-',time_scale,sig_2,':o','LineWidth',2 );
```

[image]